# Abstract classes, inheritance and virtual destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, virtual

Even though `B`'s destructor isn't `virtual`, I still can call `C`'s destructor through `B` pointer.

Does this mean that only the only outermost abstract class needs to have a `virtual` destructor?

And if so, why does it work like this?

Is it becase `B` is inheriting `A`'s destructor?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A\n";
    }

    virtual void
    function_a() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    /*
    virtual ~B() {
        std::cout << "~B\n";
    }
    */

    virtual void
    function_b() = 0;
};

struct C : B {
    ~C() override {
        std::cout << "~C\n";
    }

    void
    function_a() override {
        std::cout << "function_a\n";
    }

    void
    function_b() override {
        std::cout << "function_b\n";
    }
};

int
main() {
    B * b = new C();

    b->function_a();
    b->function_b();

    delete b;
}
```

Comment: Destructors are functions too. If base class declares it as virtual, all derived classes do so as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstand whether or not ~B is virtual. ~A is virtual so, how could ~B not be?  Same for ~C, it'll be virtual too. Because ~A is virtual.  Just because you didn't explicitly mark it virtual doesn't mean it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor of `B` and `C` are both `virtual` too. Destructors won't be inherited, but if the base class' destructor is [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual), the derived destructor overrides it and is also `virtual`; despite of `virtual` is specified explicitly or not.

> Even though destructors are not inherited, if a base class declares its destructor `virtual`, the derived destructor always overrides it.

and

> Then this function in the class Derived is also `virtual` (whether or not the keyword `virtual` is used in its declaration) and overrides `Base::vf` (whether or not the word `override` is used in its declaration).